# add edit view remove gives page not found 404 on grocery CRUD

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, grocery-crud

I'm new to groceryCRUD and i am tryng to display a simple table with all functionalities, the implementation is not in the index method as reccomanded in the tutorial.

i am using a wamp

base url:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/main_folder/';
```

controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
        $this->load->helper('url');
$this->load->view('home');
}
    public function categorie()
{

        $this->load->helper('url');
$this->load->library('grocery_CRUD');
        $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
        $crud->set_table('categorie');
        $crud->set_subject('Categoria');
        $crud->fields('nome','descrizione','note');
        $output = $crud->render();

        $this->load->view('categorie',$output);
}
}
```

the view is very long due the css theme i used so i will include the relevant (i think) parts:

```
<?php foreach($css_files as $file): ?>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://<?php echo $file; ?>" />
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php foreach($js_files as $file): ?>
    <script src="http://<?php echo $file; ?>"></script>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php echo $output; ?>
```

when i click on add edit and view i get a 404 error from codeigniter with urls i can see are not good:

```
http://localhost/main_folder/index.php/localhost/main_folder/index.php/categorie/add
```

i tryed to put the base url back to:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

but the url comes up very strange:

```
http://[::1]/main_folder/index.php/categorie/add
```

i also tryed to put the http:// :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/pannello_preventivi/';
```

like this i managed to have a clean url:

```
http://localhost/main_folder/index.php/categorie/add
```

but still getting 404 error, can someone help me please?

Comment: I get 404 if the GC is called within index function if you use it in a function with a different name edit/add/remove worked

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that codeigniter requires a route for avery action called so is enaugh to modify the routes.php in the codeigniter config folder and add every route, i did this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['categorie'] = 'welcome/categorie';
$route['categorie/add'] = 'welcome/categorie/add';
$route['categorie/insert'] = 'welcome/categorie/insert';
$route['categorie/insert_validation'] = 'welcome/categorie/insert_validation';
$route['categorie/success/:num'] = 'welcome/categorie/success';
$route['categorie/delete/:num'] = 'welcome/categorie/delete';
$route['categorie/edit/:num'] = 'welcome/categorie/edit';
$route['categorie/update_validation/:num'] = 'welcome/categorie/update_validation';
$route['categorie/update/:num'] = 'welcome/categorie/update';
$route['categorie/ajax_list_info'] = 'welcome/categorie/ajax_list_info';
$route['categorie/ajax_list'] = 'welcome/categorie/ajax_list';
```

and on that page it all works like a charm.
if you want a parametric solution that works for the same controller:

```
$route['(:any)/add'] = 'welcome/$1/add';
$route['(:any)/insert'] = 'welcome/$1/insert';
$route['(:any)/insert_validation'] = 'welcome/$1/insert_validation';
$route['(:any)/success/:num'] = 'welcome/$1/success';
$route['(:any)/delete/:num'] = 'welcome/$1/delete';
$route['(:any)/edit/:num'] = 'welcome/$1/edit';
$route['(:any)/update_validation/:num'] = 'welcome/$1/update_validation';
$route['(:any)/update/:num'] = 'welcome/$1/update';
$route['(:any)/ajax_list_info'] = 'welcome/$1/ajax_list_info';
$route['(:any)/ajax_list'] = 'welcome/$1/ajax_list';
$route['(:any)/read/:num'] = 'welcome/$1/read';
$route['(:any)/export'] = 'welcome/$1/export';
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by setting correctly `base_url` on `config.php`:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://yourdomain/appname/';
```

...hope that this helps someone else.